# Reading in an excel worksheet in C# is giving values that are the wrong worksheet

Tags: c#, excel

I am attempting to read an excel workbook that contains 5 worksheets. No matter what I do, it reads in the last worksheet only. Don't get why and it is driving me crazy.

```
        Application xlApp = new Application();
        Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+@"Tables.xlsx");
        _Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets[4];
        Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
```

Will return worksheet 5.

```
        Application xlApp = new Application();
        Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+@"Tables.xlsx");
        _Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets["Table 4"];
        Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
```

Still returns 5 (5 is labeled "Table 5")

Any help would be great. Appreciate ya.

Comment: use `Sheets` property instead `(Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets["Table 4"]`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Also reading in 5th worksheet.